# How to refer an External UIView from Button Action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am a newbie in iOS development. I have created a UIView and a button programmatically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIView* mainView = self.view;
mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIView* rotateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 120, 260, 260)];
rotateView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Wheel"]];
rotateView.layer.cornerRadius =130;
rotateView.tag = 1;
[mainView addSubview:rotateView];



UIButton *btnAct = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btnAct addTarget:self
           action:@selector(btnClicked:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnAct setTitle:@"GO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnAct.frame = CGRectMake(160.0, 450.0, 80.0, 80.0);
[mainView addSubview:btnAct];


}
-(void)btnClicked:(id)sender{

CGRect bezViewFrame = CGRectMake(122, 120, 77, 94);
UIView* testView2 = [[BBbezierView alloc]initWithFrame:bezViewFrame];
testView2.backgroundColor   = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView* Views1 = [[UIView alloc] viewWithTag:1];
Views1.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
[Views1 addSubview:testView2 ];


}
```

But it doesn't work. I want to create my 'BBbezierView' as the sub view of 'rotateView'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line

```
UIView* Views1 = [[UIView alloc] viewWithTag:1];
```

Does first create a new `UIView` and than tries to find a view on it with the tag 1. of course that doesn't exist, so it returns nil. You have to search on your viewController's view for it. And for better readability of the code, name variable names with lowercase letters:

```
UIView* rotateView = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
```